# Java AWT bounds

Tags: java, awt

I have an assignment to draw a certain number of circles using `java.awt.Graphics`.

Drawing the circles is fairly simple, but I am only supposed to draw the circle if it appears within the visible area. I know I can call method `getClipBounds()` to determine the drawing area, but I'm having trouble finding a java implementation of a way to determine if a circle intersects a Rectangle.

Is that the right way to go about determining if the circle I want to draw will be completely visible or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the Graphics.fillOval(...) method to do the painting.

Instead you can use the `Graphics2D.fill(Shape)` method. You can create oval Shape objects using the `Ellipse2D` class.

> but I'm having trouble finding a java implementation of a way to determine if a circle intersects a Rectangle.

The `Shape` object has a method that will allow you to get the rectangular bounds of the `Shape`. Then you can use the Rectangle.contains(...) method of the your Graphics area to determine if the Shape is fully contained within your panel.

Check out [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for more information and ideas.

Answer (score 1):

use Ellipse2D.Float to instanciate an object for example:

```
Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
```

basically the parameters,from left to right, are: Height, Width, X of the Top left and Y of the top left, and by keeping the X and Y both greater or equal to zero, your circle will always be visible.

the parameters of the Float(...) are documented for the Ellipse2D.Float in Java SE 7 in

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.Float.html